# Pushsharp 4 - switch between production and Sandbox

Tags: c#, pushsharp

I need to switch between production and sandbox when using PushSharp.

Below is the line of code that causes me the issue :-

```
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, @"[CERTPATH]","[PASSWORD]");
```

The certificate path and passwords are stored in the web.config which means i can easily change these setting when deploying to production.

Its changing the ApnsServerEnviroment i also need to be able to configure :-

> ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox

In the future i want to implement PushSharp notifications as a service. But for now, its simple a class inside an application.

Comment: How about making an app setting in web.config for the environment, then just have an if clause there that checks which environment is set, and based on that choose Sandbox/Production?

Comment: Yeah, i can go with that. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making my comment an answer: just make an app setting for the environment and make an if clause that checks the environment setting, and based on that chooses sandbox or production.